# How can I display an attribute below a product?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

For example I am setting up a store that sells music in Magento and I want the title of the product to just be the album name, I then have attributes such as 'artist' and 'format' that I would like to display below the title.

So for example it would display the title of the album, then below it would display the artist and the format ie 'CD'.

How can I do this?

Comment: have u created attribute for both and you are unable to display value of attribute on your page ?

Comment: You should first go to the `Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes` find `artist` attribute in grid. Click on that attribute and select yes from `Used in Product Listing` drop-down

After that re-index attribute `Admin -> System -> Index Management -> Select Product attribute check box` and click on submit.
Goto `app/design/frontend/[package]/[yourthemen]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and now able to print your attribut any where in this page by calling product object `echo $_product->getArtist();` if this select option then `echo $_product->getAttributeText('artist');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display any product attribute below Product name.

Use this to display `format` :

```
<?php echo $_product->getFormat(); ?>
```

For `artist`, use:

```
<?php echo $_product->getArtist(); ?>
```

In view page (**/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**), you can place this code after `<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>`

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $_product->getFormat(); ?></p>
<p><?php echo $_product->getArtist(); ?></p>
```

If your attributes are of `dropdown` type, use :

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('format'); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('artist'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, which file would I put this PHP code in?

Comment: wanna show this in product view page ?

Comment: @Oli Tuck: Does this helps ?

Comment: I will try it today and let you know, and will make sure to accept your answer etc

Comment: this worked when you go onto the products, but I wanted to display the attributes when you are browsing products before you go onto a specific product

Comment: do you mean LIST page ?

Comment: Yeah I worked out how to do it with list.phtml though thanks for your help

Comment: do you know how I can display these attributes on the product in the cart as well? I tried using the php that worked for the product view and list but I got this error 'Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getArtist() on a non-object in ;'

Answer (score 1):

You need to create attribute. Then you need to add below code in

**app/design/frontend/your-theme/your-package/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('your_attribute_code'); ?>
```

add above code just after below code so your attribute value show after product title

```
<div class="product-name">
    <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works when viewing a product, but how would I do it when you are browsing products, so that when you see all of the products the attributes are displayed below the title there?

Comment: do you know how I can display these attributes on the product in the cart as well? I tried using the php that worked for the product view and list but I got this error 'Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getArtist() on a non-object in ;'